# SFDX deploy error : Infinite Loop Detected

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, org

I am new to SFDX. I have been assigned to deploy a local salesforce directory to an org on salesforce. But I am getting the following error and there is no more details about the error. I tried searching the internet but to no avail. I just want to know what is this error related to ? Maybe a hint can help me solve it.

```
Error: Infinite Loop Detected:
```

[image]

Comment: did you try this - You probably have app.js-meta.xml on the root folder (force-app/main/default/lwc), while it should be on the app folder (force-app/main/default/lwc/app)

ref - https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:crZIKLhaeEEJ:https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/280650/trailhead-convert-lightning-web-components-open-source-to-salesforce-stuck-in+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in

Comment: What if I told you that I don't have this app.js-meta.xml for lwc ? then ?

Comment: then, maybe some more details would be helpful.

Comment: Ok  I will look into it thanks for the info

Comment: I just re retrieved the local directory components from the source org and then deployed it. Now it is working. Maybe the local directory got corrupted somehow.

Comment: Possibly, glad to know you deployed it.

Comment: well, I just hit the same issue.

Comment: turned out to be garbage in the lwc directory.