# VS Code - SFDX: Retrieve Source From Org > WARNING: Infinite loop detected

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin

#### Summary

*SFDX: Retrieve Source From Org* (`sfdx force:source:retrieve`) throws the error `WARNING: Infinite loop detected.`

#### Steps To Reproduce:

1. From `manifest\package.xml` launch *SFDX: Retrieve Source From Org*

- or attempt to download an Apex class via the Org Browser extension
- or run `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ApexClass:CustomClassName` from the terminal

#### Expected Result

Existing components are overwritten and/or new source org components are downloaded to the project folder.

#### Actual Result

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "WARNING: Infinite loop detected.",
    "exitCode": 1,
    "commandName": "SourceRetrieveCommand",
    "stack": "Error: WARNING: Infinite loop detected.\n    at guardedWhile (C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.80.0-b979aae708\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\dist\\lib\\source\\bundlePathHelper.js:24:19)\n    at Function.buildFullNameFromFilePath (C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.80.0-b979aae708\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\dist\\lib\\source\\bundlePathHelper.js:85:9)\n    at LightningComponentBundleMetadataType.getFullNameFromFilePath (C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.80.0-b979aae708\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\dist\\lib\\source\\metadataTypeImpl\\bundleMetadataType.js:19:52)\n    at SourceLocations.addFilePath (C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.80.0-b979aae708\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\dist\\lib\\source\\sourceLocations.js:86:62)\n    at SourceLocations.buildIndices (C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.80.0-b979aae708\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\dist\\lib\\source\\sourceLocations.js:130:26)\n    at async SourceLocations.init (C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.80.0-b979aae708\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\dist\\lib\\source\\sourceLocations.js:46:13)\n    at async Function.create (C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.80.0-b979aae708\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\kit\\lib\\creatable.js:31:9)\n    at async SourceWorkspaceAdapter.init (C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.80.0-b979aae708\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\dist\\lib\\source\\sourceWorkspaceAdapter.js:80:32)\n    at
  async Function.create (C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.80.0-b979aae708\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\kit\\lib\\creatable.js:31:9)\n    at async SourceRetrieve.retrieve (C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.80.0-b979aae708\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\dist\\lib\\source\\sourceRetrieve.js:47:20)\n    at async SourceRetrieveCommand.execute (C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.80.0-b979aae708\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\dist\\lib\\source\\sourceRetrieveCommand.js:32:16)\n    at async SourceRetrieveCommand.execLegacyCommand
  (C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.80.0-b979aae708\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\dist\\ToolbeltCommand.js:149:29)\n    at async SourceRetrieveCommand.run (C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.80.0-b979aae708\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\dist\\commands\\force\\source\\retrieve.js:32:16)\n    at async SourceRetrieveCommand._run (C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.80.0-b979aae708\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\command\\lib\\sfdxCommand.js:93:40)\n    at async Config.runCommand (C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.80.0-b979aae708\\node_modules\\@oclif\\config\\lib\\config.js:173:24)\n    at async Main.run (C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.80.0-b979aae708\\node_modules\\@oclif\\command\\lib\\main.js:27:9)\nOuter stack:\n    at Function.wrap (C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.80.0-b979aae708\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\core\\lib\\sfdxError.js:171:27)\n    at SourceRetrieveCommand.catch (C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.80.0-b979aae708\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\dist\\ToolbeltCommand.js:248:46)\n    at async SourceRetrieveCommand._run (C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.80.0-b979aae708\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\command\\lib\\sfdxCommand.js:97:13)\n    at async Config.runCommand (C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.80.0-b979aae708\\node_modules\\@oclif\\config\\lib\\config.js:173:24)\n    at async Main.run (C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.80.0-b979aae708\\node_modules\\@oclif\\command\\lib\\main.js:27:9)\n    at async Main._run (C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.80.0-b979aae708\\node_modules\\@oclif\\command\\lib\\command.js:43:20)\n    at async Object.run (C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.80.0-b979aae708\\dist\\cli.js:32:20)",
    "warnings": []
  }
```

When attempting to download from Org Browser extension
[image]

Comment: Is this a question for us or is it better suited to be posted to the force.com cli github issues tracker? https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues

Comment: "Us" being the collective salesforce.stackexchange.com community?

Reason for posting here is I'm not sure if this is an actual "issue", as in a bug.

Or something wrong that is setup on my machine.

Comment: Have you already ran `sfdx update` as well VS Code update? If not, install updates and see if this issue persists. Also, authenticate to the org again before trying to replicate this problem.

Comment: yep tried both.  sfdx-cli: Updating CLI... already on latest version: 7.80.0-b979aae708

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/313169/sfdx-deploy-error-infinite-loop-detected), this could also happen if the local directory is corrupted. Could you create a new SFDX project and try to replicate the problem? May be use a totally new org just for the sake of testing.

Comment: Creating a brand new project seems to have fixed the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Though it came back again.  So now I have go through the trouble of recreating a new project.  Would like to understand the root cause to avoid this.